# MySql - UPDATE from one database to another database

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

*FYI:  I have tried using other solutions that have been posted to resolve this query, but haven't had any success. I have decided to use the code below as it seems the most logical to accomplish my task.  However, if there is a solution that is completely different, that is fine - as long as it works.*

Within the same server, there are two databases with the same field names.

Both DBs:
ID,
users,
pwds,
emails

I am trying to grab all passwords from DB#2 (correct pwds) and move them to DB#1 (incorrect pwds) based upon each user's email address.  Unfortunately, I cannot use ID's as they are different for each user per database.

The code below is not working.  I am not receiving any errors - it's just not making the update.

Also, I realize that this type of coding has been deprecated.  If anyone has this solution using newer syntax, that would be great.

```
<?php

$dbhost1="localhost";
$dbname1="aaaaaa";
$dbuser1="bbbbbb";
$dbpass1="cccccc";

$dbhost2="localhost";
$dbname2="dddddd";
$dbuser2="eeeeee";
$dbpass2="ffffff";

$conn1 = mysql_connect($dbhost1, $dbuser1, $dbpass1);
$conn2 = mysql_connect($dbhost2, $dbuser2, $dbpass2, true);
if(! $conn1 || ! $conn2 )
{
  die('Could not connect to db1 or db2: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db('db1', $conn1);
mysql_select_db('db2', $conn2);

$query = "UPDATE db1.users as t1, db2.users as t2 SET t1.pwds = t2.pwds WHERE t1.emails = t2.emails";

// LINE BELOW ADDED AFTER COMMENTS POSTED:
mysql_query($query, $conn1);

mysql_close($conn1);
mysql_close($conn2);

?>
```

Comment: You are not running the query.

Comment: Even if in your case you don't use any user input, mysql_ functions are unsafe. Prefer using mysqli_ functions or pdo

Comment: echo the $query and see if any problem is there or use error_reporting(E_ALL) to check error this will give better idea.as @Loger said use pdo or php extension mysqli.

Comment: Don't use mysql_query but mysqli_query. mysql_query is outdated!

Comment: I realize that I'm asking you to do my work for me... but would it be possible for you to post the safer version of this code?  Your posting would also help many others in the future.  Thanks.

Comment: 1.  Should 'mysql_select_db()' be before or after the query?  2.  I receive an access denied for each DB as I change the mysql_query($query, $conn1) coding for $conn1/$conn2.  It seems, as soon as I 'cross' the query vs the DB, the access is denied.  ??

Comment: also... FYI: I have gone back to ensure that all DB settings are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The folks that posted about the missing line of code regarding the **mysql_query()** were exactly correct.  However, I felt the need to continue on with this posting - to accentuate this information - for others also searching for this solution.

The actual problem was that both users needed to be assigned to both DBs and given ALL PRIVILEGES for both DBs.  As long as I was accessing one DB at a time, everything was fine.  As soon as I coded two users and two DBs, the access error occurred.

TIP:  As was mentioned above also, add the extra lines of code to display the errors.  I've learned my lesson.  Thanks to all.

**...and one last INSANELY important thing was the updated syntax for the actual query:**

```
$query = "UPDATE db1.users INNER JOIN db2.users ON (db1.users.emails = db2.users.emails) SET db1.users.pwds = db2.users.pwds";
```

Answer (score 1):

after `$query` construction line use this line:

```
mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: Don't use mysql_query but mysqli_query. mysql_query is outdated!

Comment: i know for @mar2195 answer i have posted and i have suggested him the same.

Answer (score 0):

Missing the `mysql_query()` after the `$query`

You just write like that

if you want to update in $conn1 then

```
mysql_query($query, $conn1);
```

And if you want to update in $conn2 then

```
mysql_query($query, $conn2);
```

Comment: I've updated my original posting to include the missing line of code.  I just ran the script but it still is not updating the DB. ?

Comment: Don't use mysql_query but mysqli_query. mysql_query is outdated!